# Foundation orbit with v-for in a vue component

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, vue-component, vuejs2, orbit

I have a `foundation orbit` that requires some data from the database, this data includes the image captions and some text. I am using a `vue component` as follows:

```
...
<template>
    <div class="contemporary orbit" role="region" aria-label="Contemporary Pictures" v-f-orbit>
        <div v-for="development in components.other_developments">
        <ul class="orbit-container" style="height: 500px">

            <h1 class="other-developments-orbit-title">{{development.name}}</h1>

            <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
            <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>

            <p class="other-developments-orbit-text">{{development.description}}</p>

            <a class="other-developments-orbit-button button" id="custom-button">VISIT WEBSITE <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>

            <li class="is-active orbit-slide" data-use-m-u-i="false">
                <img class="other-developments-image orbit-image" :src="development.image_url" alt="Space">
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
...
```

I need to fetch all the information from an api, it fetches the first one and piles up the rest under it instead of sliding. Where can I place the `v-for directive` for it to slide with all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found this yet but a better solution would be to use [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/)